# Retorno de Autorização Nfe 3.10 (MG) C#

Tags: nfe

Estou com uma dificuldade na hora do retorno da autorização da NF-e utilizando C# (Visual Studio 2008). Está retornando um objeto vazio.

Para ser feita a chamada do WS estou utilizando o seguinte código:

```
public string NFeAutorizacao(string XmlEnvio, string VersaoSchema, short Ambiente, short CodIbgeUfEmi, string SiglaWS, string PathCertificado, string SenhaCertificado, ref string MsgErr, ref short FlagErr)
    {
        try
        {
            // Converte dados do xml para XmlNode
            XmlDocument oXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            oXmlDoc.LoadXml(XmlEnvio);
            XmlNode oNode = oXmlDoc.DocumentElement;
            // Carrega o certificado
            X509Certificate certificado = new X509Certificate();
            certificado = SelecionarCertificado(PathCertificado, SenhaCertificado, ref MsgErr, ref FlagErr);

            // Se conseguiu localizar o certificado digital
            if (FlagErr == 0)
            {
                // Identifica  o WebService a ser utilizado: "SEFAZ Estadual", "Ambiente Nacional" ou "SCAN"
                switch (SiglaWS)
                {
                    case "SEFAZEST": // WebService da SEFAZ Estadual ou Virtual
                        // Identifica o ambiente a ser utilizado
                        switch (Ambiente)
                        {
                            //Ambiente de Homologação
                            #region
                            case 2: // HOMOLOGAÇÃO
                                // Identifica o código IBGE do Estado
                                switch (CodIbgeUfEmi)
                                {
                                    case 31: // MG
                                        // Declara as variáveis do WebService

                                        MG.NfeAutorizacao.Homologacao.NfeAutorizacao wsMG = new BibliotecaNFe.MG.NfeAutorizacao.Homologacao.NfeAutorizacao();
                                        MG.NfeAutorizacao.Homologacao.nfeCabecMsg nfeCabecMsgMG = new BibliotecaNFe.MG.NfeAutorizacao.Homologacao.nfeCabecMsg();
                                        MG.NfeAutorizacao.Homologacao.nfeDadosMsg nfeDadosMsgMG = new BibliotecaNFe.MG.NfeAutorizacao.Homologacao.nfeDadosMsg();

                                        // Coloca os valores no cabeçalho

                                        nfeCabecMsgMG.cUF = CodIbgeUfEmi.ToString().Trim();
                                        nfeCabecMsgMG.versaoDados = VersaoSchema;
                                        wsMG.nfeCabecMsgValue = nfeCabecMsgMG;
                                        nfeDadosMsgMG.Any = new XmlNode[] {oXmlDoc};
                                        nfeDadosMsgMG.Any[0] = oNode;

                                        // Coloca o certificado
                                        wsMG.ClientCertificates.Add(certificado);
                                        wsMG.Timeout = 120000;

                                        // Comunica com o WebService
                                        string obj = nfeDadosMsgMG.Any[0].OuterXml;
                                        Console.WriteLine(obj);

                                        string retorno = wsMG.NfeAutorizacaoLote(nfeDadosMsgMG).ToString();
                                        Console.WriteLine(retorno);


                                        return wsMG.NfeAutorizacaoLote(nfeDadosMsgMG).ToString();
                                    default: // Código não foi informado ou é inválido
                                        FlagErr = 1;
                                        MsgErr = "Erro: Código da UF informada " + CodIbgeUfEmi.ToString().Trim() + ". Código inválido ou SEFAZ não possui WebService próprio.";
                                        return "";
                                }  // switch (CodIbgeUfEmi)

                            default: // Ambiente incorreto (Diferente de 1 e 2)
                                FlagErr = 1;
                                MsgErr = "Erro: Ambiente informado: " + Ambiente.ToString().Trim() + ". Informe um código de ambiente válido.";
                                return "";
                        }  // switch (Ambiente)
                            #endregion

                    default: // WebService não informadou ou parâmetro incorreto
                        FlagErr = 1;
                        MsgErr = "Erro: Sigla do WebService a ser utilizado " + SiglaWS.Trim() + ". Informe um código válido.";
                        return "";
                }  // switch (SiglaWS)
            }
            else
            {
                return ""; // Retorno em branco pois houve erro
            }  // if (FlagErr == 0)
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            FlagErr = 1;
            MsgErr = "Erro: Não foi possível enviar o lote de NF-e à SEFAZ. " + e.Message + " - " + e.StackTrace.ToString();//"Erro: Não foi possível enviar o lote de NF-e à SEFAZ. " + e.Message + "\n" + e.InnerException.ToString() + "\n" + e.StackTrace.ToString();
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Beleza... É realizada a comunicação com a SeFaz e autorizada a nota (se você consultar a chave de acesso, ela estará lá normalmente)
Porém dentro do método do WS, quando é realizado o "Invoke", é retornado um objeto vazio.

No webservice, é nessa linha:

```
object[] results = this.Invoke("NfeAutorizacaoLote", new object[] {
                    nfeDadosMsg});
```

o Results[] retorna um objeto sem valores...

Estou com essa dificuldade pois necessitava do XML de retorno para atualizar a NF-e em meu sistema.

Gostaria de saber o que estou fazendo errado nessa chamada ou na instanciação do retorno?

Para auxilio, estou disponibilizando o vídeo da operação com breakpoints:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/xyj4l82k7djhxbq/Dificuldade%20SeFaz%20MG%20Retorno.camrec?dl=0

E estou disponibilizando a parte do código demonstrado:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/d2ndqa4nos4p72z/BibliotecaNF310.7z?dl=0

Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te expliquei "anteriormente" tem o um erro na configuração do webservice MG, **logo acima de:**

> object[] results = this.Invoke("NfeAutorizacaoLote", new object[] {
>   nfeDadosMsg});

**Procure por:**

> [return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("retEnviNFe",
>   IsNullable=false)]

**E altera para:**

> [return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("retEnviNFe",
>   Namespace = "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe", IsNullable=false)]

No código disponibilizado, a linha mostrada acima não foi adicionada, tive que adicionar novamente.
A resposta é um array de objetos, não pode simplesmente transformar em string.
No código que você comentou

> //return rsp[8].OuterXml;

mostro como pegar o valor

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu li sim, Hub. Inclusive te enviei alguns e-mails com respostas e até um vídeo com a operação. Realizei a alteração que você disse e está apresentando a mensagem "Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto", como já informado.

Comment: Veja resposta atualizada @Thales

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, @Hub Irei testar.

Comment: Deu certo @Hub! Muito obrigado.

Comment: De nada @Thales