# Envio NFe para MG na Versão 3.10

Tags: nfe

Após as dicas alterei o código do método bem como apliquei as correções no web service mudando de:

```
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("retEnviNFe", IsNullable:=False)
```

para:

```
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("retEnviNFe", [Namespace]:="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe", IsNullable:=False)
```

Entretanto recebo como retorno um objeto vazio. Meu Deus o que tem de errado?
Alguém já teve sucesso no envio (3.10) para MG?
Segue o método alterado:

```
        Public Function enviaNFe_(ByVal NumeroDoLote As Integer, ByVal ListiView As ListView, ByVal Label As ToolStripStatusLabel) As Boolean
    Dim ret As Boolean = False
    Dim result() As String
    Dim xmlDoc As XmlDocument = Nothing
    Dim arquivoRetorno As String = Nothing

    Try
        'vrifica a existência do arquivo
        If File.Exists(Me.ArquivoXml) = True Then

            Me.labelMsg.Visible = True
            Me.labelMsg.Text = Space(40) & "Aguarde um instante por Favor. Enviando o arquivo...."
            My.Application.DoEvents()

            'Carrega o arquivo xml para dentro do objeto xmlDoc
            xmlDoc = New XmlDocument
            xmlDoc.Load(Me.ArquivoXml)
            'Cria um objeto XmlNode
            Dim oNode As XmlNode = xmlDoc.DocumentElement

            'Seleciona o certificado digital e devolve o xml assinado
            If Me.SelecionarCertificado = True Then

                'Define o cabeçalho
                Dim NFeCabecMsg As pNfeAutorizacao3.nfeCabecMsg = New pNfeAutorizacao3.nfeCabecMsg
                With NFeCabecMsg
                    .cUF = "31"
                    .versaoDados = "3.10"
                End With

                'Dados da NFe
                Dim NFeDadosMsg As pNfeAutorizacao3.nfeDadosMsg = New pNfeAutorizacao3.nfeDadosMsg
                NFeDadosMsg.Any = New XmlNode() {xmlDoc}
                NFeDadosMsg.Any(0) = oNode

                'Envia o arquivo .xml (Consome o WS)
                Dim oWS_pNFeAutorizacao3 As pNfeAutorizacao3.NfeAutorizacao = New pNfeAutorizacao3.NfeAutorizacao
                With oWS_pNFeAutorizacao3
                    .Url = "https://nfe.fazenda.mg.gov.br/nfe2/services/NfeAutorizacao.asmx"
                    .nfeCabecMsgValue = NFeCabecMsg
                    .Timeout = 50000
                    .ClientCertificates.Add(Me.X509Cert)
                    .SoapVersion = Web.Services.Protocols.SoapProtocolVersion.Soap12
                    result = New String() {.NfeAutorizacaoLote(NFeDadosMsg).ToString}
                End With
            End If
        End If

        '...aqui eu trataria o retorno (result)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Erro no envio da NFe.", "Gestor .NET" & vbNewLine & ex.ToString, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Tem certeza? Verificou aqui (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50629/retorno-de-autoriza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-nfe-3-10-mg-c/50720#50720) que o retorno é um objeto e não uma string? @yelar

Comment: Sim, o retorno é do tipo 'System.Object()', mas partindo do principio que tudo no .net é um objeto quando faço ".NfeAutorizacaoLote(NFeDadosMsg).ToString" se houvesse alguma informação ela não seria convertida para um objeto do tipo string? O problema é que retorna um System.Object() sem valores.O retorno fica assim: result {Lenght=1} (0) "System.Object[]". Você poderia, se possível postar ou enviar um e-mail mostrando como pegar este retorno? Desculpe, espero não estar abusando.

Comment: Veja este exemplo: http://1drv.ms/1EFJESd @yelar

Answer (score 1):

Um modo de pegar em `string: result(0)(0).OwnerElement.OuterXml` , depois é só converter para *XML*. Nesse caso é no retorno da *ConsultaProtocoloNFe MG*.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que você só está tendo problema para ler o valor dessa variável.

No meu caso fiz assim e conseguir pegar o retorno.

```
    Dim result As Object
    result = servidor.consultaCadastro2(cabecalho, dados)

    MsgBox(result(0)(2).OuterXml)
```

O mais difícil foi descobrir que o servidor de MG estava com problema. O que acho um absurdo.