# C# Como ler XML de Retorno de Envio da NFe

Tags: c#, web-service, nfe

Estou implementando a comunicação com o WS da SEFAZ. Após o envio da Nota, estou com dificuldade de obter conteúdo XML do retorno em formato string e ler o Recibo.("infRec")
Segue print screen com a retorno preenchido, alguém sabe como faço para converter esse retorno e ler os valores como falei acima ( String XML e Campo Recibo)?  Segue o código da requisição.

```
        NfeAutorizacao.NfeAutorizacao aut = new NfeAutorizacao.NfeAutorizacao();
        aut.ClientCertificates.Add(certificado);

        nfeDadosMsg dados = new nfeDadosMsg();

        aut.nfeCabecMsgValue = new nfeCabecMsg();
        aut.nfeCabecMsgValue.cUF = "31";
        aut.nfeCabecMsgValue.versaoDados = "3.10";
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(param);
        XmlNode newnode = xml.DocumentElement;
        Object[] res = aut.NfeAutorizacaoLote(newnode);
```

[image: Código do retorno do envio]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Seja bem vindo, recomendo fazer um [tour], de forma a enquadrar sua pergunta nos moldes do SO-pt. O Ideal é postar juntamente com a pergunta o código que já tentou, para avaliação e mais facilidade na resolução do problema

Comment: Tente esta solução: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50629/retorno-de-autoriza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-nfe-3-10-mg-c?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Qual é a exception que está retornando para vc?

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi, não ocorre nenhuma. Eu preciso pegar o res[0] e salvar      em XML para depois Ler os dados do XML campo a campo. Acho que preciso converter XMLNode[] para um XMLNode. Como fazer ?

Comment: Faz um breakpoint, Shift+F9, faz um watch em `res` e navegue até onde precisa. Vc verá como recuperar o que precisa.

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi obrigado pela ajuda!! tive que serializar o res[0] e salvar o conteúdo serializado  arquivo XML. Deu certo.