# Consumir WebService NFeDistribuicaoDFe - VB.NET ou C# - Manifestação/Download NFe

Tags: c#, web-service, vb.net, nfe, download

No site da NFe Nacional (http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/webServices.aspx?tipoConteudo=Wak0FwB7dKs=) eu ja tenho um software feito em VB.NET que consome as `WEBSERVICES` (`NfeConsultaDest` E `NfeDownloadNF`) porém devido a uma nova norma técnica estas `webservices` serão descontinuadas.
 
Ja esta em vigor o novo `WEBSERVICE` (`NFeDistribuicaoDFe`) para manifestão/download de notas fiscais.
Alguem tem alguma base pronta para que eu possa pelo menos achar o "caminho das pedras" de manifestação e download (por chave de acesso NFe ou Lote) ?

Comment: Ate o momento que eu sei esse web service já esta funcionando, inclusive eu estou consumindo ele para as consultas. essa é a url: https://www1.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/NFeDistribuicaoDFe/NFeDistribuicaoDFe.asmx se estiver usando esse posso te ajudar em algo, minha aplicação é em java. o que estou pesquisando é como fazer para manifestar a nota e consultar se ela esta manifestada ou não, o que aparentemente não esta disponível na consulta desse novo serviço.

Comment: Me ajudaria muito, eu tendo a base de como consultar ja abre pelo menos um caminho aqui

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53209/nfe-3-10-webservice-mg?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Acho que a essa altura você já deva ter conseguido, mas como essa semana passei por esse mesmo ponto descobri muitas coisas.
Mesmo com o certificado Digital válido não conseguia referenciar os metodos do web service na minha solution então salvei o WSDL e o converti em classe. Feito isso consegui gerar um xml e realizar o envio da solicitação para o donwload.

Para converter o WSDL em classe utilizei o terminal do visual studio 2017 lá vc tem apontar seu arquivo e ele converte.

```
wsdl C:\caminho so seu arquivo
```

Simples assim, depois só jogar a classe em seu projeto. Ah estou fazendo em C#.

O retorno é uma String com os documentos zipados, ai vc tem q recolher a tag  e realizar a conversão.